# R and RGoogleDocs - trouble with auth

Tags: r, google-docs

here's the deal with RGoogleDocs: when I run:

```
auth = getGoogleAuth("mymail@gmail.com", "my pass",service="wise")
```

I always have this (I try different login/passw):

```
Error in strsplit(ans, "\\\n") : non-character argument
```

I am trying different ways for it with no success. Please help, what's wrong? And 
may be there're any other packages for connect R and Google sheets? Thanks

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 Day later:

I fix it with library(googlesheets), that works fine